# $H^n(X,G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(H_n(X), G),$ for any space $X$ or for any chain complex $\mathcal{C}$, yes or no.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, hom-functor

Here is the question I am trying to understand it:

Prove or give a counter-example.

$(a)$ $H^1(X,G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(X), G),$ for any space $X.$

$(b)$ $H^n(X,G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(H_n(X), G),$ for any space $X.$

$(c)$ $H^1(\mathcal{C},G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(\mathcal{C}), G),$ for any chain complex $\mathcal{C}$ of free abelian groups.

How can I think about these statements? Should I start thinking using the universal coefficient theorem and when the ext functor vanishes or what(say for letter (c))? How about if I am speaking for spaces not chain complexes what should I do?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I think the only UCT that we have in Hatcher's  for cohomology is for chain complexes of abelian groups .... But then we also know that the first cohomology group is just the Ext functor if we have a free resolution for the space..... But then what?

Comment: Of course you should be thinking about the relevant universal coefficient theorem

Comment: I think the only UCT that we have in Hatcher's  for cohomology is for chain complexes of abelian groups .... But then we also know that the first cohomology group is just the Ext functor if we have a free resolution for the space..... But then what? @FShrike

Comment: @freakish what do you mean by shift? Can you elaborate more please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The universal coefficient theorem for cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology) (UCT) says that there is a short exact sequence of the form

$$0\to \text{Ext}^1(H_{n-1}(X),G)\to H^n(X,G)\to \text{Hom}(H_n(X), G)\to 0$$

for any abelian group $G$.

> $(a)$ $H^1(X,G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(X), G),$ for any space $X.$

It is true. Because $H_0(X)$ is always free abelian group, and therefore $\text{Ext}^1(H_0(X),G)=0$ regardless of the choice of $G$.

> $(b)$ $H^n(X,G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(H_n(X), G),$ for any space $X.$

That is false. For a counterexample pick $X$ such that $H_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H_2(X)=0$, for example the real projective plane $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$. Then $\text{Ext}^1(H_1(X),G)=G/2G$ from general properties of $\text{Ext}$. In particular if we choose $G=\mathbb{Z}$, then $$\text{Ext}^1(H_1(X),\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2$$
$$\text{Hom}(H_2(X),\mathbb{Z})=0$$

and therefore $H^2(X)=\mathbb{Z}_2$ which is not isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(H_2(X),\mathbb{Z})=0$.

> $(c)$ $H^1(\mathcal{C},G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(\mathcal{C}), G),$ for any chain complex $\mathcal{C}$ of free abelian groups.

Take chain complex $\mathcal{C}$ associated with $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ from the previous example (which of course is of free abelian groups). Define a new chain complex $\mathcal{D}$ by $\mathcal{D}_n=\mathcal{C}_{n+1}$, and analogously we shift boundary operators. So it is just $\mathcal{C}$ with all indexes moved to the left by $1$.

Then $H_n(\mathcal{D})=H_{n+1}(\mathcal{C})$ and $H^n(\mathcal{D},G)=H^{n+1}(\mathcal{C}, G)$. And therefore $H^1(\mathcal{D},G)$ is not isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(H_1(\mathcal{D}), G)$ because $H^2(\mathcal{C},G)$ is not isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(H_2(\mathcal{C}), G)$ by previous counterexample.

Note that in general this construction cannot arise from a topological space (and that's why it doesn't contradict point (a)), for which $\mathcal{C}_n=0$ whenever $n<0$.

Comment: why $H_0(X)$ is always a free abelian group?

Comment: but the statement of UCT in hatcher is for chain complexes only not for spaces. How is the transition then?

Comment: It is well know that $H_0(X)\simeq\mathbb{Z}^\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the (cardinal) number of path components. Google it. As for second question, homology for space arises from a chain complex associated to the topological space (e.g. singular chain complex), and so UCT applies. $H_n(X)$ is just short for $H_n(\mathcal{C})$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is chain complex associated to $X$.

Comment: do we need $\lambda$ to be finite for this group to be free?

Comment: @Brain no. Here $\mathbb{Z}^\lambda$ is short for $\bigoplus_\lambda \mathbb{Z}$, which is the (possibly infinite) direct sum. Those groups are free. See this: https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Zeroth_homology_is_free_on_set_of_path_components

Comment: you mean the direct product of $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Brain [the direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of (possibly infinitely many) copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. Some authors use the term "direct product" for the same thing, but sometimes it means something different (i.e. the Cartesian product). I don't remember which one Hatcher uses. Either way, we are talking about all "sequences" (formally choice functions) which have all coordinates except for finitely many as zeros.

Comment: ln $(c),$ why you are saying shifted to the left? Is $\mathcal{D}$ a chain or cochain complex? I think it is a chain also, am I right? ..... But how will we get $D_0$ then?

Comment: It's a chain complex. I just change indexes. I don't understand the question. And I don't know how to explain it in an easier way, the definition of $\mathcal{D}$ is there.

Comment: I got you thank you!